# How to convert entire list in a column to string to pass into API?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, api-design

I need to pass a comma seperated string into an api.

currently df looks like this:

```
id      tags
1       ['dc','independent_press','exclusive_variants','marvel']
```

The API docs for tags found [here](https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_edit) say that I need to pass in a string like so:

```
'comics,marvel,dc,batman'
```

How can I convert the list in the `tags` column into a string so the df looks like this:

```
id      tags
1       'comics,marvel,dc,batman'
```

I would like to pass this string into the api like so:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
            params = {
                'id': row['id'],
                'tags':row['tag'], 
                }
            r = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
            print(r)
```

I tried a string replace like so:

```
df.tags.str.replace('[',"'")
```

but got result:

```
0   NaN
```

edit:

dataframe head in dict:

```
{'Email': {0: 'test@test.com'},
 'subcategory': {0: 'comics'},
 'category': {0: 'comic'},
 'id': {0: '1'},
 'is_new': {0: 1},
 'tag': {0: 'dc, independent_press, exclusive_varients, marvel'}}
```

Comment: Try df.tags = df.tags.apply(','.join)

Comment: @Vaishali this is what it looks like now `[,,,',,,d,,,c,,,',,,,,,, ,,,',,,i,,,n,,,d,,,e,,,p,,,e,,,n,,,d,,,e,,,n,,,t,,,_,,,p,,,r,,,e,,,s,,,s,,,',,,,,,, ,,,',,,e,,,x,,,c,,,l,,,u,,,s,,,i,,,v,,,e,,,_,,,v,,,a,,,r,,,i,,,e,,,n,,,t,,,s,,,',,,,,,, ,,,',,,m,,,a,,,r,,,v,,,e,,,l,,,',,,]
`

Comment: What is the output of df.tags.apply(lambda x: type(x))?

Comment: @Vaishali this is the output I get when reset tags back `0    <class 'list'>`, tried converting to string that column

Comment: I am reopening, it. Not sure about this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like tags is just a `list` of `str`, so this should do the trick:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    params = {
        'id': row['id'],
        'tags': ','.join(row['tags']), 
    }
    print(params)

    r = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
    print(r)
```

Comment: Perfect this is it!